# What is the stainless steel baseboard in a walk-in cooler/freezer?

Tags: code-compliance, metal, baseboard, inspection

Trying to identify this base molding that I want to match in a walk-in cooler at a supermarket.  It is missing from a few sections of the cooler and needs to be installed.

Is this anything special, part of the walk-in assembly kit, or just a piece of stainless steel that someone cut to place at the base to pass inspection?!

[image: base moulding]

Comment: It’s aluminum channel that attaches to the floor. Then the panels are set into it and attached with short screws through the channel.

Comment: I thought so too, Kris, but then how could it be missing? I assume it's just an L angle.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like galvanized steel to me. It  probably came with the walk-in panels from the manufacturer.

You can get small pieces of galvanize steel at your home center,  I don’t know what application you are going to use it for but you could try looking in the roofing flashing department of the store for longer pieces.

Or  you can get any size  and Gauge you like at a steel supply house.

Comment: The " spangle " pattern shows that it is galvanized steel.